# Is it possible to hide dash video source url?

Tags: html, node.js, video-streaming, html5-video

I would like to know it is possible to hide or encrypt url of video chunks or can I protect the file in any other way from downloading?

Answer (score 0):

I think DRM protection will do this job.

Comment: I have already tried using raw key encryption but still dash manifest reveals url to s3 storege

Answer (score -1):

Well, On the internet nowadays almost nothing is source protected, especially in an HTML page or a Video object. Using external services to embed the content can allow you to restrict embedding, but any user with access to a browser's network activity tab can see the sources of the video / media on the page.

I hope embedding on some external source could assist you.